# How to show this atlas is maximal on the sphere $S^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have the following problem:

> Let $S^n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\|x\|=1\}$ and $\pi_{\pm}:S^n\setminus\{{p_{\pm}}\}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be the stereographic projections from the poles $p_{\pm}=(0,...,\pm 1)$. Then $$\mathcal{A}=\{(S^n\setminus\{{p_+}\},\pi_+),(S^n\setminus\{{p_-}\},\pi_-)\}$$
>
> is a maximal atlas in class $C^{\infty}$.

I already showed that $\pi_+$ and $\pi_-$ are homeomorphism. Obviously the sets $S^n\setminus\{{p_{\pm}}\}$ cover $S^n$. And $\pi_+$ and $\pi_-$ are $C^{\infty}$-compatible.

The hard thing is that I really don't know how to show this atlas is maximal. I mean, if we take $(U,\phi)$ any chart $C^{\infty}$-compatible with both $(S^n\setminus\{{p_+}\},\pi_+),(S^n\setminus\{{p_-}\},\pi_-)$, how to show $(U,\phi)\in\mathcal{A}$?

Thank you.

Comment: It isn't. For any other two points of $S^n$ used as poles you obtain other stereographic projections $\notin\mathcal A$ and these are compatible with the given charts. (And of course there are *many* more compatible charts)

Comment: You basically _never_ explicitly construct or define a maximal atlas. You simply define a couple of charts and say "Let $\mathcal A$ be the maximal atlas containing these charts." Maximal atlases are _huge_ (not in the cardinality sense of huge, but in the sense of how much time and space it would take to describe all the charts in there)